# HTML Form add requirement image

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add an image after my input field. This image will disappear once the form requirement has been met. I found a way to add the image to the field itself using css and input:required:invalid but the requirement for this project is to have it outside the field with html img tag.

the code I have so far (snippet)

```
<label for="FIRST">Name:  
<input required type="text" name="FIRST" placeholder="First" size="35" id="FIRST"><span id = "sadFace"><img src="sad.png" id="sad"></span></label>
<label for="LAST"></label>
```

this puts the image in the place I want it but i don't know how to make it disappear once the field has been filled correctly.

i tried adding to css:
 #sad.required{/* some design elements */}

but this did not modify the image at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the ":valid" pseudo-class to accomplish your task. This is a working code for your situation:

```
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        /* select the #sadFace preceded by a valid input */
        input:valid ~ #sadFace {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- html -->
    <label for="FIRST">
        Name:  
        <input required type="text" name="FIRST" placeholder="First" size="35" id="FIRST">
        <span id = "sadFace">
            <img src="img/imgA.png" id="sad">
        </span>
    </label>
```

Comment: This does the job, thank you. It also moves my last name input box when the face is removed. Is there a way to replace the gap? or should I just use a static positioning on form elements?

Comment: what do you mean by moving the last name. are you putting the image between the first and the last name ?

Comment: Yes they are on the same line and he image is in between them

Comment: I have understood. So, try to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. If you need something else let me know.

Comment: `visibility: hidden` hides the element  while leaving the space where it was.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using (`#sad.required`) refers to an element that has an `id='sad'` and `class='required'`. I'm assuming you mean to refer to the child `img` element of every `input` that is required; you should use `input[required] #sad` as your selector if that is the case.

You should note that setting the required attribute to false will not exclude an img from the selector above since a value has not been specified and the selector only requires the existence of the attribute to match.

Answer (score 0):

$('#pass').keyup(function(){

```
    if($(this).val()!='')
       $('#show').hide() //or may be with an effect
    else
       $('#show').show()
```

});